# Can the SMPS IC works only with power from startup resistors without using Aux winding power?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

my turbo charger burned out.in the circuit, the smps ic's VCC connected to 230VAC using start up series resistor and also to aux winding power. My question is, will the smps ic work if it is powered only from startup resistor(general case)?.. Here the startup series resistor is followed by a capacitor(ie. RC circuit is used for Start up).[image]

Comment: If the SMPS IC could work properly without the Aux winding, why would the Aux winding be there ? If it could be omitted that might save cost and make the design simpler. So if it is there, obviously it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the part and the design of the circuit. There's no general answer for "SMPS ICs"

Many could work without an aux winding supply at the expense of size and efficiency. (The resistor would have to dissipate lots of power all the time.)

If you add some specific details we can make the answer more specific as well.

Comment: Thanks, 
Thats all i need. in my case the start up circuit and power from aux are isolated each other using a transistor. whenever aux power is active this transistor become on state connect to VCC of smps ic along with start up circuit. If im directly shorted these aux and startup circuit will there be any problem. transistor marking is "1AM" and smps IC marking is "8110B" that only i know about them ( part number cant found).
@rohathkilic

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOgWl.png above attached image is IC marking

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about ICs like UC2843 then **no, it cannot**.

Capacitor plus startup resistor pair can supply the chip until the end of the first *(right after powering on)* switching action. From then on, current consumption increases due to the on-chip oscillator and the need of driving a heavy capacitive load *(G-S junction of the MOSFETs - a few nanofarads)*.

So if there were no aux winding to supply the chip, the capacitor next to the startup resistor will discharge very quickly and the switching action will begin afresh from the start. This will cause the converter to stop and barely turn on again and again.